# How would I set the state of a react component when I resize my screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this navbar component that takes in a button component. I wrote code that is supposed to hide the button when the window reaches 960px, but for some reason it's not working with the function I wrote. I put spaces between the code to show which lines I'm referring to

```
      function Navbar() {
        const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

        const showButton = () => {
          if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
            setButton(false);
          } else {
            setButton(true);
          }
        };

        return (
          <>
            <nav className='navbar'>

              <div className='navbar-container' showButton={showButton}>
   
                <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                  <li className='nav-item'>
                    <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                      Home
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
             
                {button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>SIGN UP</Button>}

              </div>
            </nav>
          </>
        );
      }
```

So right now if I set the button state to false it will disappear.

```
 const [button, setButton] = useState(false);
```

Also, if I replace my function name with onMouseEnter it will disappear, but I would need to hover over the button

```
    const onMouseEnter = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
          setButton(false);
        } else {
          setButton(true);
        }
      };

  <div className='navbar-container' onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}>
```

So I know my state is updating with my logic when I resize the screen to 960px because the function onMouseEnter only hides the button when I hover over it at 960px

But I don't understand why my original function name isn't automatically hiding the button when I resize the screen to 960px?

Is there a specific function I need to name in React for resizing screens??

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onresize , this is what you need.

Comment: @devd I don't get what you're showing me on that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first:
//
why your first function did not trigger:
A function can be triggered by many ways, you can simply invoke it or you can invoke it on events like click, mouse enter etc but you are invoking your function nowhere.

Second thing:
//
How can you solve that problem
To solve this problem you need to listen to resize event
You can add resize event listener on window or on body

```
window.addEventListener("resize", showButton);
```

//
Although,there are a lot of other better ways to add event listener.

Third thing:
How to check the screen size on first load:
if you are using Hooks::

```
  useEffect(() => {
       showButton();
  },[]);
```

If you are using class:

```
    componentDidMount(){
         showButton();
 }
```

These two are triggered after the very first render.

Comment: so I added that line and so far the button disappears when I resize the screen, but once I refresh the screen it shows up again. Is there a way to make sure once the screen size is 960px that the button will never show up regardless if I refresh or not?

Comment: If I am able to solve your problem then ,please hit up button and mark the answer as correct- Thank you

Comment: it only works once I resize the screen, but when I refresh the page it pops up again and I need it to be permanently hidden in mobile view under 960px

Comment: Please check the code , I had already updated it for refresh scenario.

Comment: ah I didn't see the useEffect update. Thanks that got it to work!